# Swagger ignore functions from resource

Tags: spring, cxf, swagger

when I'm trying to configure everything for swagger, it's working.. somehow partially, it ignores functions from resource and consider only @Api adnotation of the class

I'm using apache cxf + spring

Generated json contains only class description, no methods here

```
..."apis":[{"path":"/","description":"Entities operations"}]...
```

The controller adnotations

```
@Path("/")
@Api(value = "/", description = "Entities operations")
@Controller
public class RepositoryResource
....
```

The function adnotation

```
@GET
@ApiOperation(value = "Method to check if this resources is up and running")
public String hello()
...
```

Log message spoted

```
 Could not find a definition for bean with id {http://listing.jaxrs.swagger.wordnik.com/}ApiListingResourceJSON.http-destination
```

spring configuration

```
<jaxrs:server id="restAPI" address="/" staticSubresourceResolution="true">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="swaggerResourceJSON"/>
        <ref bean="repositoryResource"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
 ....
```

Comment: See also "How to hide endpoints from OpenAPI documentation with Springdoc" -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/62102261/873282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a root ("/") for your `@Api` value - that would break the documentation. Even if you have `@Path("/")`, you should have something like `@Api("/root")`.

This does not affect the API itself, only where the documentation is served.

Once you make that modification, your /api-docs would look like:

`..."apis":[{"path":"/root","description":"Entities operations"}]...`

And that resource would be available on /api-docs/root. Running it with swagger-ui will produce the proper API calls.