# How to restrict users from seeing swagger endpoint docs but not using them?

Tags: django, swagger

We want users to be able to see only a few swagger docs based a django permission given to them, but we don't want to restrict them from using other endpoints that they don't have permission to view.
Swagger docs don't provide a way to do this (or at least I haven't seen).
Has anyone done this?

Comment: "we don't want to restrict them from using other endpoints that they don't have permission to view" - that seems a bit back-to-front to me. Why would you not want to allow users access to the documentation of the end points they are _allowed_ to use?

Comment: The api endpoints are general, so they are used acorss the website (not by the user). We only want to show certain endpoints on the swagger docs.

Comment: That makes sense. Does this answer help you?
[How to hide endpoints from OpenAPI documentation with Springdoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62110788/243925)