# Springboot openapi generating duplicate apis in swagger document

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Java: 21

Springboot: 3.2.1

OpenApi dependency:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Open api yaml file

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Example apis
  description: |-
    A simple collection of example APIs
  version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
servers:
  - url: http://127.0.1:8091/api/v1
    description: Local server (uses test data)
  - url: https://example-dev.com/api/v1
    description: UAT server (uses test data)
  - url: https://example.com/api/v1
    description: Production server (uses live data)
tags:
  - name: example
    description: example apis
paths:
  /examples:
    get:
      summary: Get examples
      description: Get examples
      operationId: getExample
      responses:
        200:
          description: Success
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Example'
        404:
          description: Leaderboard not found
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ExampleNotFoundError'
  
components:
  schemas:
    Example:
      type: object
      properties:
        creatorId:
          type: string
        hipiCoins:
          type: number
    ExampleNotFoundError:
      type: object
      properties:
        creatorId:
          type: string
        hipiCoins:
          type: number
```

In swagger, there are two apis

One is `GET /api/v1/examples` and another is `GET /examples`

Expected only `GET /api/v1/examples`

There are few similar questions in stacker flow, I tried all of them one by one in last 8 hours, none is solving the issue.

Controller code:

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen",
    date = "2024-01-15T23:26:32.308871+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]")
@Controller
public class ExampleController implements ExampleApi {

  private final ExampleApiDelegate delegate;

  public ExampleController(
      @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required = false)
          ExampleApiDelegate delegate) {
    this.delegate = Optional.ofNullable(delegate).orElse(new ExampleApiDelegate() {});
  }

  @Override
  public ExampleApiDelegate getDelegate() {
    return delegate;
  }
}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.application.name=example-service
server.port=8091
springdoc.enable-native-support=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui
logging.level.root=INFO
```

Comment: pls add your api code, I think there is maybe a `@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1")` in your api code.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori I have just added controller file code, please have a look at it.

Comment: could you add your `application.properties` or `application.yml`, maybe there is a `server.servlet.context-path` in it.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori updated with application.properties please have a look and thank you for your response on this.

Comment: Sry I do my best but nothing found by now.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori no issues, thank you for your kind effort.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori I resolved this issue and posted below.

Comment: Congratulation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets resolve with below changes

In pom.xml

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <skipValidateSpec>true</skipValidateSpec>
              <inputSpec>./src/main/resources/example.yaml</inputSpec>
              <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
              <apiPackage>com.example.openapi.api</apiPackage>
              <modelPackage>com.example.openapi.model</modelPackage>
              <supportingFilesToGenerate>
                ApiUtil.java
              </supportingFilesToGenerate>
              <configOptions>
                <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
              </configOptions>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Now in target folder it generates `ExampleApiDelegate` and `ExampleApi` both, but we need to extend `ExampleApiDelegate`

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen",
    date = "2024-01-15T23:26:32.308871+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]")
@Controller
public class ExampleController implements ExampleApiDelegate {

  private final ExampleApiDelegate delegate;

  public ExampleController(
      @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required = false)
          ExampleApiDelegate delegate) {
    this.delegate = Optional.ofNullable(delegate).orElse(new ExampleApiDelegate() {});
  }

  @Override
  public ExampleApiDelegate getDelegate() {
    return delegate;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your path as:

```
paths:
  /api/v1/examples:
    get:
```

Comment: Already tried, still tries to create one with `/api/v1/examples` and another `/api/v1/api/v1/examples` and changing server urls does not work either.

Comment: see this similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102261/how-to-hide-endpoints-from-openapi-documentation-with-springdoc

Comment: @Noshaf I do not want to hide any end point, it is just end points are coming twice in swagger.